# I'm trying to setup a WCF Service that is called via the MsmqIntegrationBinding and I'm getting an error

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

System.InvalidOperationException: The MsmqIntegrationBinding validation failed. The service cannot be started. The MsmqIntegrationBinding binding does not support the method signature for the service operation.

I'm working from the following sample [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)
The only setting I've changed is I need to use the ActiveX Serialization Format.

Interface

```
namespace MQTest
{
    //MSMQIntegrationBinding
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMQService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void GetData(string value);
    }
}
```

Service

```
 public class MQService : IMQService
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Get base address from appsettings in configuration.
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Test/Service");

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and provide the base address.
            using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (IMQService), baseAddress))
            {
                // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start listening for messages.
                serviceHost.Open();

                // The service can now be accessed.
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                Console.WriteLine("The service is running in the following account: {0}",
                                  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
        }
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
        public void GetData(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MQTest.MQService">
                <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\outbound_adt_a08"
                                        binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="OrderProcessorBinding"
                          contract="MQTest.IMQService">
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>

        <bindings>
            <msmqIntegrationBinding>
                <binding name="OrderProcessorBinding" serializationFormat="ActiveX">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </msmqIntegrationBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel >
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the interface must accept an MsmqMessage

I changed my interface and it's working now.
Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: Ahh I was writing an answer :) FYI, when using an `Accept="*"` OperationContract, the method MUST accept only one `Message` parameter (in that case, a `MsmqMessage<T>`).